# RLlib- installation on mac m1

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, apple-m1, ray

I've used **anaconda** to run **rllib** on my **m1 pro** laptop.

used the following instructions:

```
conda create -n rllib python=3.8
conda activate rllib
pip install cmake "ray[rllib]"
pip install torch
```

However, I get the module ray is not found("`No module named 'ray.rllib'; 'ray' is not a package`").

pip list -> `include ray == 1.11.0`

main.py:

```
from ray.rllib.agents.ppo import PPOTrainer
```

Comment: Have you accidentally named one of the python files in your project `ray.py`?

Comment: @FlyingTeller you are correct, my bad, waste of 3 days of my life. (u can add an answer and i will mark it as correct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you installed it correctly.

You might just have a file called `ray.py` in your project which is shadowing the actual module. If so, rename it and your import should work.